# Query Geopackage using spatial index in QGIS DB manager

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, geopackage, spatial-index, dbmanager

I would like to do spatial join in QGIS DB manager on geopackage database.
The query should look like this

```
select * from Soil_C_cadaster a, 
(select * from Soil_C_cadaster
where forest_c is null) b
where st_touches(b.geom,a.geom)
```

It's a cross join on the same layer with 13000 not so complex features but I'm limiting it to some 200 features in table **b**. Query takes more than two minutes, so I'm suspecting it's not using spatial index by default as would PostGIS with spatial predicate.

Here is example of tested polygons:

[image]

In post like [this](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2017/03/dealing-with-huge-vector-geopackage.html), there's written about use but just with one layer and search bounding box, not with more layers. I can't imagine how to write it correctly.

Comment: I rather installed PostGIS and did the same query that took **155 s** in just **0.4 s**.

Answer (score -1):

You could use **ST_UNION** to speed up your query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM soil_c_cadaster a, 
  (SELECT ST_UNION(geom) as geom FROM soil_c_cadaster WHERE forest_c IS NULL) b
WHERE ST_TOUCHES(b.geom,a.geom)
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I need too aggregate some statistics of neighbouring polygons, so dissolving is not the way. Btw. ST_UNION takes more time than plain select of **b** table.